# Создается не 10, а 110 потоков в Java, почему?

Tags: java, многопоточность

На курсах дали такое задание: `Необходимо создать 10 потоков и пул только из 2 потоков. Пул должен выполнять действие: выводить имя потока и i, которое увеличивается с 0 до 10. Проследите, чтобы одновременно выполнялись только 2 потока.`

Я, как мне показалось, сделал верно и вывод получается правильный - каждый поток выводится 10 раз и с каждым разом увеличивает i, программа завершается тогда, когда каждый поток выводит 10.

Однако учитель в ревью сказал, что я создал 110 потоков, а не 10, моя проблема в том, что я не понимаю каким образом это сделал и как это исправить. Вот код:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxThreads = 2;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executor;
        threadPoolExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize(maxThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 11 ; i++) {
            Runnable thread = new MyThread("Поток Олег "+i);
            Runnable thread2 = new MyThread("Поток Витя "+i);
            Runnable thread3 = new MyThread("Поток Виталик "+i);
            Runnable thread4 = new MyThread("Поток Слава "+i);
            Runnable thread5 = new MyThread("Поток Ян "+i);
            Runnable thread6 = new MyThread("Поток Иван "+i);
            Runnable thread7 = new MyThread("Поток Даня "+i);
            Runnable thread8 = new MyThread("Поток Влад "+i);
            Runnable thread9 = new MyThread("Поток Давид "+i);
            Runnable thread10 = new MyThread("Поток Даниил "+i);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread2);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread3);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread4);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread5);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread6);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread7);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread8);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread9);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(thread10);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Потоков не создается, используется пул потоков с 2 потоками.

Comment: Если считать количество объектов MyThread - вы создаёте 10 объектов в каждой итерации, вы создали цикл на 11 итераций - итого 10 * 11 = 110

Comment: Странное задание. Создать 10 потоков и пул из 2 потоков. Может 10 Runnable?

Comment: @andreymal глупо, что я этого не знал, спасибо!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

При каждом значении i Вы создаете 10 потоков.

- i=0, создали 10 потоков.
- i=1, создали еще 10 потоков(уже 20 с    предыдущими).
- i=2, создали еще 10 потоков(уже 30 с предыдущими) и    т.д.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Условие задачи: `Необходимо создать 10 потоков и пул только из 2 потоков. Пул должен выполнять действие: выводить имя потока и i, которое увеличивается с 0 до 10. Проследите, чтобы одновременно выполнялись только 2 потока`. И теперь ваш ответ непонятно как решает эту проблему.

Comment: А автору вопроса понятно и для меня это главное :))) Для меня, кстати, стало открытием то, что многие русскоговорящие программисты задают вопросы на иностранном сайте stackoverflow, а не тут. Но чем больше читаю комментарии, тем понятнее почему это так. К сожалению многих экспертов здесь волнует совершенно иные вопросы, нежели помощь и обмен опытом.  И можете удалять мой комментарий, я своего мнения не изменю ;))))))))

Comment: Поясню для Романа, что мой ответ решает эту проблему "Однако учитель в ревью сказал, что я создал 110 потоков, а не 10, МОЯ ПРОБЛЕМА В ТОМ, ЧТО Я НЕ ПОНИМАЮ КАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ ЭТО СДЕЛАЛ и как это исправить." и порекомендую прочитать статью Хорстманна, в которой он говорит о социальном долге программистов, а он (Хорстманн К.) все-таки уважаемый человек, и можете опять удалять мой комментарий